# How to convert "2016.05.09 15:45:45" into 1462788945000?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, epoch

I have no idea how to implement this. Please describe how to do it correctly.

```
datetest = "2016.05.09" + " "+ "15:45:45"
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime(datetest, "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M")
epocht =  d.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: shouldn't the answer be 1462788945 instead of 1462788945000?

Comment: Why? It's milliseconds since Unix epoch, the format used by JavaScript for example.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
from datetime import time
timestamp = int(time.mktime(d.timetuple())) * 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
import time
import datetime

t = datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 9, 15, 45, 45)
print(time.mktime(t.timetuple() * 1000))
```

Comment: This will give the wrong number, it's seconds instead of milliseconds as asked by the OP.

Comment: The OP should specify explicitly.

Comment: It's clear from the title. The OP specifies, based on an example, how the transformation should work: "How to convert “2016.05.09 15:45:45” into 1462788945000?"

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

datetest = "2016.05.09" + " "+ "15:45:45"
d = datetime.strptime(datetest, "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
t = d.timetuple()
res = int(time.mktime(t)) * 1000
print(res)  # -> 1462833945000
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the dateutil parser as it offers some flexibility, but others may disagree

In [1]:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as dateparse
datetest = "2016.05.09" + " "+ "15:45:45"
dateparse(datetest).timestamp() * 1000
```

Out [1]:

```
1462830345000.0
```

'dateparse' returns a datetime.datetime object:

In [2]:

```
dateparse(datetest)
```

Out[2]:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 9, 15, 45, 45)
```